# Edge browser : High contrast accessibility : text background is not coming same as div background

Tags: css, accessibility, high-contrast

I am working on high contrast accessibility. I am facing a weird issue here. In the normal mode text is taking same background color as parent's background-color (for example DIV) but in high contrast mode text background is coming black though parent's background-color is different.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6pz3fx22/2/).

CSS

```
.test {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    height: 50px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast:active) {
    .test{
        background-color: #1BEAFE;
    } 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test2">
    hi there alok
    </div>
</div>
```

Shortcut-key for high contrast : `Shift`+`Alt`+`PrtScrn`

Issue: 
[image]

Expected result:

[image]

***Note: This is working fine in IE. It's only problem with Edge browser(Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393 and Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0)***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805775/preventing-high-contrast-mode-in-edge-from-adding-background-to-text